# Using ODE Event Location and using Solution at Event as Input into ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I have been attempting to re-create a plot found in the following paper:

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0964-1726/4/4/006/meta

The plot I am trying to re-create is on page 267 top right hand corner, specifically, $x(t)$ vs. $t$.

The ODE used in the paper is
$$m\ddot{x}(t)+k_0x(t)+k_1(x(t)-x_s)=0$$
where $x_s$ is a piece-wise constant function defined by $x_s=x(t_r)$ whenever $\dot{x}(t_r)=0$.

The plot is generated using the values $m=1,k_0=150,$ and $k_1=50.$

The code to solve this is given as:

```
tstart = 0;
tfinal = 2;

tspan = [tstart tfinal];
u0 = [1; 0];
refine = 4;
options = odeset('Events', @resetevent , 'OutputSel' , 1, 'Refine', refine);

tout = tstart;
uout = u0';
teout = [];
ueout = [];
ieout = [];
ue = [];
while tout(end) < tfinal

% Solve until the first terminal event.
[t, u, te, ue, ie] = ode45(@(t,u) sys(t, u, ue), [tstart tfinal] , u0, options);

% Accumulate output.  This could be passed out as output arguments.

nt = length(t);
tout = [tout; t(2:nt)];
uout = [uout; u(2:nt,:)];
teout = [teout; te];          % Events at tstart are never reported.
ueout = [ueout; ue];
ieout = [ieout; ie];


% Set the new initial conditions, with .9 attenuation (??).

u0 = [u(nt,1) ; u(nt,2)];

% A good guess of a valid first timestep is the length of the last valid
% timestep, so use it for faster computation.  'refine' is 4 by default.
options = odeset(options,'InitialStep',t(nt)-t(nt-refine),...
    'MaxStep',t(nt)-t(1));

tstart = t(nt);
end

figure(1)
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(tout,uout(:,1));
title(['Time history of $x(t)$'],'interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
ylabel('$x$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(tout,uout(:,2))
title('Time history of $\dot{x}(t)$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
ylabel('$\dot{x}$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

subplot(2,1,1);
stairs(teout,ueout(:,1))
title('Time history of $x_s(t)$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

% 
function dz = sys(t, z , us)
dz = zeros(2,1);
if isempty(us) == 1
    us = 0;
else
    us;
end

% if isempty(us) == 1
%     us = 0;
% elseif us(1) == 1
%     us(1) = -1;
% else
%     us;
% end

m = 1;
k0 = 150;
k1 = 50;

dz(1) = z(2);
dz(2) = - ((k0 + k1)/m)*z(1) + (k1/m)*us(1);
end


% Reset Event Function
function [lookfor, stop, direction] = resetevent(t, z)
% Locate the time when xdot passes through zero in any direction
% and stop integration.
lookfor = z(2);  % when xdot = 0
stop = 1;        % stop the integration
direction = 0;   % any direction
end
```

The plot produced with `u0=[1 ; 0]` is 
[image]

The plot produced with `u0=[1 ; -eps]` is 
[image]

The plot produced with `u0=[u(nt,1) ; 0]` as the restart initial condition is
[image] 
I have a couple questions related to this:

1. What's confuses me is that for some reason Matlab does actually find
   the first zero of $\dot{x}$ and inputs into the function, but the
   documentation on [ODE Event Location](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html#bu7whe8) says it skips the first
   terminal event. It's probably something I'm doing wrong, but I can't
   see what it is.
2. If you look at plot for $\dot{x}(t)$, at the points where it passes     through zero, I have the initial conditions start with the
   last value it ended with and it gives a kink in the plot, which means the derivatives don't match. I tried
   using 0 as the initial value, which makes sense to me, but it causes the solver to diverge. Yet, it seems like the derivatives match slightly better.
   I'm not sure what the 0.9 attenuation does and I tried messing with
   that to no avail.

If you use the commented code in the function `sys` it will force the value of `us` and the plot will look like the one in the paper, but it's too specific and not what I'm trying to do, since I want to extend this idea of resetting to a different ODE.

I also noticed that if I set the initial condition to `u0 = [1 ; -eps]` it will start practically at zero, but not register as exactly zero, and thus produce the correct plot.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is this too long of a question? Can I do anything to get some assistance on how to figure out what is going on with the ODE Event Location?

Comment: Your question is not so much on how to use software but on the effects of software on your solution. This is slightly off-topic here, you might have better success at scicomp.stackexchange.com. -- To be better understood, you should say that `xs(t)` is piecewise constant with the value `xs(t)=x(te)` taken at the apex points `dotx(te)=0`. -- It would be helpful to have access to the graphs mentioned in the questions. (And yes, a jump in the second derivative gives a kink in the first derivative.)

Comment: You should set the maximum time step to a third or a quarter of the period of the oscillation `m*u''+(k0+k1)*u=0`, if you care to set it at all. That is, `dtmax = pi/2/sqrt((k0+k1)/m)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion. I will make the necessary edits to fix for clarity. I'll also check out scicomp.stack.exchange.com and see where it goes.

Comment: As to question 1), the exact language is "during the first step of the integration", but your first event is in the initial conditions, before the first step. Which would mean that with `u0=[1 ; +eps]` this limitation is met and the first zero crossing would be ignored.